# Promised never to smoke or promised never smoking

Tags: grammar

I saw this problem from some textbook:

> A - "My father promised never to smoke."
>   B - "My father promised never smoking."

I know the correct answer is A because it feels right.

But what is the proper reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Promise* takes *to*-infinitival clauses as complements:

> 1. My father *promised* **never to smoke**.

But it doesn't take *V-ing* clauses as complements:

> 2. *My father *promised* **never smoking**.　*(ungrammatical)*

Unfortunately, you just have to memorize which kinds of complements each verb can take.  In the case of *promise*, it takes one and not the other.

With a different verb, the opposite might be true:

> 3. *My father never *enjoyed* **to smoke**.　*(ungrammatical)*
> 4. My father never *enjoyed* **smoking**.

*Promise* can also take a noun phrase as a complement, and in English it is possible to derive nouns from the *-ing* form of a verb:

> 5. One of Mr. Mbeki's first trips was to Mali, where he *promised* **funding and training** for conservators like Traore at South Africa's national libraries in Cape Town and Tshwane.

In this example, *promise* takes the long noun phrase starting with *funding and training* as a complement.  You might think that your example with *smoking* could work in the same way.  However, it can't because *never* forces us to interpret *smoking* as a verb:

> 6. My father *promised* **smoking**.　*(grammatical with smoking as a derived noun)*
> 7. *My father *promised* **never smoking**.　*(ungrammatical)*

Example 6, however, requires a specific context to make sense:

Imagine that I told you that I was opening a club, and in defiance of California law, my club would definitely have smoking. And then when the club finally opened and you came to visit, you found out I couldn't have smoking there after all, and you were quite upset. "You promised me there would be smoking," you'd say. "**You promised smoking!** There's no smoking here!"

In that sort of context, *smoking* as a derived noun makes sense.  We can tell by the phrase *no smoking* that *smoking* is a noun; this is different from the clause *never smoking*, in which *smoking* is a verb.

Answer (score 1):

Remove **never** from the examples for a moment.

It's possible to promise (something to) a person.
Who did he promise?

> He promised Jane.

And it's possible to promise some *things*

> He promised fidelity/love.

You can also promise to do certain things.

> He promised to marry.
>
> He promised to return.

But you can't promise *smoking* any more than you can promise sitting or standing or swimming. It simply makes no sense.

In the same way you can't promise **never smoking**.

But you can promise **never to smoke**.